# How do I use arguments together with bash aliases

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

Today, I learned the very handy trick:

> man [some command] -t | open -f -a Preview

I'd like to create an alias in my .bash_profile file as a shortcut. In order for this to work, I need to pass an argument into the aliased command. A little poking around and I came up with this:

> alias manp="man $1 -t | open -f -a Preview"

This almost works, but if I type in, say "manp ls", it seems to be expecting the ls manpage to be in whatever my current directory is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to aliases. Aliases are just text substitutions without further logic.

But you can use shell functions to achieve the same result:

```
function pman() {
    if [ -x /usr/bin/open ]; then
        man -t "$1" | open -f -a Preview
    else
        man "$1"
    fi
}
```

The if-then-else part is there just to make sure it also works on non-OSX systems.

To define a function, just include the definition from above into your `~/.bash_profile`. Usage is identical to aliases or any other command: `pman ls`.

As @stuffe pointed out in a comment keeping aliases/functions in a separate file has its advantages (especially it allows you to re-read your aliases/functions into the current shell without executing any setup stuff from `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`). To do this, create a separate file called `.alias`, `.functions` or similar and add

```
test -e ~/.alias && . ~/.alias
```

to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I like to keep all my functions in a separate file (functions.fn), and call that from within whatever .profile your shell of choice uses.  To expand on Patrix excellent answer, $1 is the name of the first passed argument, $2 is the 2nd etc.  For clarity and as a form of self commenting my functions the first thing I do in anything thats more than a couple of lines is rename them with moredescriptivename=$1 etc.

Comment: good point, I've extended the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I like @patrix's solution, but I just wanted to give another example, cut from my OSX's `.bash_profile` file, which in this case is setting TextWrangler to open a file that I pass as a parameter:

`function tw() { /usr/bin/open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app "$1" ;}`

I wanted to be able to more easily edit my **.bash_profile** :-)